# Online maps for Cryptid

Tags: cryptid

Are the games generated in playcryptid.com the same as those in the box, or does it generate new games?

If it's the latter, how many games are possible? The ones included in the game box feels like a small set and has a fairly limited replayability for the same group of 4 people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked with the designers on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/cryptesque/status/1709272228259319857) and co-desinger Ruth Veevers responed

"Yes, there's a different, much larger set online - I don't remember how many off the top of my head but it's something like 10,000 map setups which each contain dozens of games."